# Correct way to create a model into an embedded hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do I create a new instance of a model into an embedded hasMany relationship without sending a separate request on the commit?

This is what I am currently doing.
My models:

```
 AUI.TableMetadata = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    fields: DS.hasMany('AUI.FieldMetadata')
});

AUI.FieldMetadata = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    table: DS.belongsTo('AUI.TableMetadata')
});
```

Store setup:

```
Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();

Adapter.map(AUI.TableMetadata, {
    fields: { embedded: 'always'},
});

AUI.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: Adapter.create({}),
});
```

Creating records:

```
var table = AUI.TableMetadata.createRecord({
    name: 'Cool Creatures',
    fields: []
});

var field = AUI.Field.createRecord({
    name: 'octopi',
});

table.get('fields').pushObject(field);
table.get('transaction').commit();
```

When I commit the table, the table post correctly embeds the data, but it also sends a separate request for each of the child fields which 404s and puts the child models into a error state.

Comment: For now, this is not implemented in ember-data, please see issue [440](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/440) and [437](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/437) on the bug tracker for more information.

Answer (score 0):

#### New Syntax for DS.Model in Ember Data 1.0.0 beta

```js
AUI.TableMetadata = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    field_metadata: DS.hasMany('field_metadata')
});

AUI.FieldMetadata = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    table_metadata: DS.belongsTo('table_metadata')
});
```

#### Inside a controller or route

```js
this.store.createRecord('field_meta', { name: 'octopi' });
this.store.createRecord('table_meta', { name: 'Cool Creatures' });
```

I'm not sure if Ember is as good as detecting plurals like Rails so you may have to name `field_metadata` as `field_metadatas`. Of course, in the object for the record creation, you'll have to add the appropriate IDs (`field_metadata_id` and `table_metadata_id`) for the relationship to work.